# How to specify the result type of MatExpr?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this expression in my code:
`*h = ((*R) / ((*G) + (*R)));`
where R, G and B are Mat pointers of `uchar` since there is division I want to convert the answer into a Mat pointer of `float`

so i tried this
`*h = Mat_<float>((*R) / ((*G) + (*R)));`

but I get segmentation fault for it.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the matrix *R into floats. Use method `Mat::convert_to`. Assuming R8 is a matrix of uchar you can create float matrix as follows:

```
Mat R32; R8.convertTo(R32,CV_32F);
```

This is nicely explained in [introduction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html) to OpenCV.

Note 1: This expression `*h = Mat_<float>((*R) / ((*G) + (*R)))` performs division using uchars and later re-interpret the result as float, which is wrong. `Mat_<float>` is only to simplify element access for arrays that are already floats.

Note 2: You don't need to use pointers to Mat most of the time.

Comment: thanks, so now I get 'OpenCV Error: Bad argument (When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly speci
fied) in unknown function, file :\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\
modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1303' 
so how do I specify the output type to be a float?

Comment: Try to convert all matrixes into float using `Mat::convert_to()`.

Comment: Won't this have performance issues?
this code should run for every frame on a mobile device,
I want to do as less allocations and ofcourse runtime as possible

Comment: Yes, allocation of new float matrix will cost something. If you need to gain performance, you will need to get down to pixel-wise processing (not matrix expressions).